# How to split a string by nth intervals of alphabetical characters while also separating specific characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

If we have a

```
string s = 'abcdxefyghijxlm'
```

I can split it by 2 characters using

```
s.match(/.{1,2}/g)
```

and I will get

```
['ab', 'cd', 'xe', 'fy', 'gh', 'ij', 'xl', 'm']
```

How would I split it this way while at the same time isolating specific characters `'x'` and `'y'`?

For the example above, I would like to get the following result

```
['ab', 'cd', 'x', 'ef', 'y', 'gh', 'ij', 'x', 'lm']
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I am only targetting alphabetical characters to be split into pairs except `x` and `y`. So currently, the regex I have above does not actually work for when I have something like `s = '{"abcd":"12"}'` as it will result to

```
 ['{"', 'ab', 'cd', '":', '"1, '2"', '}']
```

instead of

```
 [ '{', '"', 'ab', 'cd', '"', ':', '"', '1', '2', '"', '}']
```

Comment: What should be the result with: `str = "axbycxdy"`?

Comment: `["a", "x", "b", "y", "c", "x", "d", "y"]`. So basically, the idea is any other letters than `x` and `y`, will look to the letter on its right if it can grab it. The letter will only grab the one on its right when it's also not `x` and `y` and he's not grabbed by his left side. Otherwise, he's alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an alternation (`this|that`): `/[a-wz]{2}|./g`

That looks for:

- `[a-wy]` - any two characters of the English alphabet except `x` and `y`, or
- `.` - any single character

Alternations choose the first that matches, so this will prefer `[a-wz]{2}` over `.` where both match.

Example:

Live Example:

```js
let s = "abcdxefyghijxlm{\"abcd\":\"12\"}";

console.log(s.match(/[a-wz]{2}|./g));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

**Note:** The above is case sensitive. If you don't want that, add the `i` flag: `/[a-wz]{2}|./gi`

Comment: I was able to do this also, I forgot to describe that I only want to group alphabetical characters in pairs (except the desired characters to isolate). I updated the post. Please see example.

Comment: Works perfectly for my use case with the `/gi` ! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
/((?![x|y|\W|\d|"])..|.)/gi
```

`(?!)` Negative Lookahead => Assert that the Regex `[x|y]` does not match
`[x|y]` Match a single character => x or y (case insensitive)
`[\W]`  matches any non-word character 
`\d` matches a digit
`g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
`i` modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of `[a-zA-Z]`)

```js
const str = `abcdxefyghijxlm{"abcd":"12"}`;

let m = str.match(/((?![x|y|\W|\d|"])..|.)/gi);
console.log(m);
```

Comment: FYI: `[x|y]` matches `x` or `y` or `|` moreover your result is different from OP's request. Reread the quesion.

Comment: oh i did'n see that. thanks mate. I've updated my answer. now its `only targetting alphabetical characters to be split into pairs except x and y` as OP's request.

Comment: With a string like: `s = '{"abcd":"12"}'` the result must be: `[ '{', '"', 'ab', 'cd', '"', ':', '"', '1', '2', '"', '}']`

Comment: so far it doesn't isolate both `x` and `y`. Something like
`'{"aBCxdEFygy":"1y"}'` results to `["{", "\"", "aB", "Cx", "dE", "Fy", "gy", "\"", ":", "\"", "1", "y", "\"", "}"]` instead of `["{", "\"", "aB", "C", "x", "dE", "F", "y", "g", "y", "\"", ":", "\"", "1", "y", "\"", "}"]`.